# Laravel relationship through pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Tables**

Companies

- id
- name

Departments

- id
- name

Company_Department

- id
- company_id
- department_id

Sales

- id
- product
- company_department_id

**Models**

Company.php

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function departments(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class)
    }
}
```

Department.php

```
class Department extends Model
{
    public function company(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class)
    }
}
```

Companies can have many departments and departments can be from a different companies (Many-to-many). But the sale is related to a company department. Company department can have many sales but a sale is from a single company department (One-to-many). I need to:

- Get sales from a company department
- Get de the company department from a sale.

I think I need to get relationship from the pivot table but dont know how.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you might want to create a model for the `Company_Department` table. This model will represent the relationship between a company and a department and will have a one-to-many relationship with the `Sale` model.

Here's how you can define these relationships:

CompanyDepartment.php

```php
class CompanyDepartment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'company_department';

    public function company(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    public function department(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }

    public function sales(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sale::class, 'company_department_id');
    }
}
```

Sale.php

```php
class Sale extends Model
{
    public function companyDepartment(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CompanyDepartment::class, 'company_department_id');
    }
}
```

Now, you can get the sales from a company department like this:

```php
$sales = CompanyDepartment::find($id)->sales;
```

And you can get the company department from a sale like this:

```php
$companyDepartment = Sale::find($id)->companyDepartment;
```

Please replace `$id` with the actual ID of the company department or sale.

Comment: In addition, since it's pivot table/model, code could be `CompanyDepartment extends Pivot {/*rest of code*/}`.

Comment: Thanks for you response! I did with a new class that extends pivot as @Tpojka said and is working. But now my question is, the relationships in the table are well done for what I want to achieve? Is strictly necessary to create that pivot class to reach it? Or could be possible to acomplish without that pivot class? For example, to do like ```$company->departments->sales``` and not ```$company->companyDepartment->sales```. Thanks again.

Comment: It's simple: for `$company->departments->sales` relation has to be established directly between departments table and sales table. Since your business logic requires relation strictly between `CompanyDepartment` and `Sale` models (`company_department` and `sales` tables) Karl's answer is way to go.

Comment: Would be any possibility to get the company of a sale on this way ```$sale->company```? Or the only way would be ```$sale->companyDepartment->company```? Something like ```HasManyThrough``` but for ```belongsTo```